# Disabling of sap.m.panel in sapui5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

How to disable sap.m.panel? I have found that there is no property as setEnabled in sap.m.panel. But the customer requirement is to disable a panel. Can anyhow panel be disabled?

Comment: What is the purpose of a disabled Panel? It allows no interactions, so I don't see your use-case yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is no property to disable the panel. But you can try to freeze that panel(**Section** Tag in Html) by using CSS property.

```
 pointer-events: none;
```

This may help you.